# Can't find style in html but can find in styleSheets

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

When i using Material-ui Box component(such as `<Box padding={2}/>`), I can't find style in html, but I can find style in document.styleSheets, why ?

[screenshot of index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REJvA.png)

[screenshot of document.styleSheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tatCE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That style rule could be from a style sheet in Shadow DOM or a [constructible stylesheet.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets)

Answer (score 0):

Those data comes on demand only. It means comes when every it requires only.

Its comes with **external CSS** file. Those are built in library it loaded with **event** accrues.

Ex:if **click** event accrues on **button** style will changes **blue** to **gray** like that.